# azure php web app not redirecting to next page

Tags: php, azure, azure-web-app-service

```
<?php
    include 'user_register_login.php';
    if (isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] === true) {
        // Redirect user to activity page
        if ($_SESSION["usertype"] == 3) {
            header('Location:user.php');
        } else {
            header('Location:moduleManage.php');
        }
    }
    ?>


<form class="form-group" method="post" name="user_login_submit"
    action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" autocomplete="off"
    id="user_login">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" class="Uname" value="<?php echo $Lusername ?>" name="Lusername"
    onselectstart="return false" onpaste="return false;" onCopy="return false"
    onCut="return false" onDrag="return false" onDrop="return false" autocomplete=off /><span
    class="error"><?php echo $LusernameErr; ?></span><br></br>
```

I was trying php webapp on azure. After login it is reloaded to the same login page without getting redirected. Since I am new to php I was trying all the ways found on internet but I couldn't figure out where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are using windows platform to create your webapp. If not, then I would suggest to use windows platform and try to create `web.config` file under the wwwroot folder, if it doesn't exist.

If you can find this file when deployed your webapp, you need to modify it. You will need to add or modify a specific content called `RewriterConfig`.

The code snippet provided by @Jason Pan below shows the format that you can use.

```php
<configSections>
 <section name="RewriterConfig" type="URLRewriter.Config.RewriterConfigSerializerSectionHandler,URLRewriter" />
</configSections>
......
<RewriterConfig>
   <Rules>
      <RewriterRule>
        <LookFor>^default/([0-9]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)</LookFor>
        <SendTo>11.aspx?id={R:1}</SendTo>
      </RewriterRule>
   </Rules>
</RewriterConfig>
...
```

Alternatively you can also implement Azure AD login to your site to enable log in via authentication with ADFS and it's an easiest and safest way to add authentication to your webapp.

You can follow this [PHP: Implement Azure AD login to your site](https://katystech.blog/2021/08/php-azuread-oauth-login/) blog for the detailed process to implement Azure AD login.

And for more information I would suggest to read this [Configure a PHP app for Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-php?pivots=platform-linux) and [Tutorial: Build a PHP and MySQL app in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-php-mysql-app?pivots=platform-linux#manage-the-azure-app) documents from Microsoft.